# Show the modal window after the php successfully called

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a form

```
<form id="email-form" action="">
  <input id="email-input" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="submit" value="Get Early Access">
</form>
```

and js

```
  $('#email-form').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
      var data = $("#email-form :input").serializeArray();
      email = data[0].value; 

      var posting = $.post("writemail.php", email);
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        if (data) {
          $('#modal-one').addClass('shown');
        };
      });
  });
```

and php

```
<?php
$username = "test";
$password = "Test123";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die(false);

echo(true);
?>
```

I need to show the modal after calling the $.post method.
In the debug I see that the class 'shown' are applied, but nothing happens...
When I toggle this class thru direct calling, all is good

```
  $('.open-dlg-btn').on('click', function(e){
    $('#modal-one').toggleClass('shown');
  });
```

Whats wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you take a look on the style inspector and compare the computed style between a scenario the 'shown' class is applied from click event and the time it applied from the done event

Comment: solved... the problem was in the specific showing the modal window via #target trick